# MVCGrid.net - Keep column header and sort icon in one line

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

I am using MVCGrid.net in my `ASP.NET` MVC website and in some cases when there is not enough space the grid will move the header of a column either on top or below of the sort icon on the right to it.
 Here is an example:
[image]

Is there any way to force the header and the icon to always stay in the same line instead of being moved on top or below of each other?

I already tried using `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow: hidden` and `display: inline-block` but none of these fixed the problem. I am currently using `min-width` as a temporary solution but this is not very elegant and depends on how long the header of a column is.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: nowrap` should do the trick, but for it to work you need to set the `table` element to have `table-layout:fixed;`

Comment: Thanks! It does work with `table-layout:fixed` but now I am getting the issue that columns with short headers are no longer wide enough for their content:
https://i.imgur.com/dfePjMz.png

Comment: Ahh ok, you can try to set the `width: auto;` for your `<td>` elements.

Comment: Or do you have a set with for the elements that cross the column border?